# How do i refactor these functions?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, refactoring, reusability

```
def function1():
    for row in rows:
        for column in columns:
            if condition:
                board[row][column] += 1
                # more code

def function2():
    for column in columns:
        for row in rows:
            if condition:
                board[row][column] += 1
                # more code
```

Both functions execute the same code if a condition is met. The condition is the same in both functions. Is there a way to write a single function so i don't have to repeat `board[row][column] += 1` and the `# more code`.

Comment: What about a function like: `modify_board(columns, rows, board)`? But if the condition is the same for both functions, as well as the loop, what is the point of having both functions? Is there something else not mentioned that makes `function1` different from `function2`?

Comment: The `function1` loop iterates through `rows`, then `columns` while the `function2` loop iterates through `columns` then `rows`. @gmdev

Comment: Ah, I see now. What does "more code" consist of?

Comment: Conditions and return statements, exactly the same in both functions @gmdev

Answer (score 1):

If the "more code" is too long, it is worth to write a function that takes `order` parameter in addition to `columns` and `rows` so it would be:

```
def function(first_items, second_items, order):
    for f_item in first_items:
        for s_item in second_items:
            if condition:
                if order:
                    board[f_item][s_item] += 1
                else:
                    board[s_item][f_item] += 1
                # more code
```

And then call like this:

```
function(rows, columns, True) // first case 
function(columns, rows, False) // second case
```

Comment: The `function1` loop iterates through `rows`, then `columns` while the `function2` loop iterates through `columns` then `rows`.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Except how do you know which is `row` or `column` in `board[row][column] += 1`

Comment: What! also didn't notice!! sorry again, I will edit the answer